# React, using image from object inside array inside div with react Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, components

I'm struggling with a small thing how to import the picture which I saved inside an object, inside of an array to display later Card Elements on my Website.

Doesn't matter what I want to try. He is showing me the name the description and the status. Even the alt is shown which I saved inside of the Data.js file.
But the picture doesn't want to display.
I tried storing the image inside of a variable and then calling the variable. Doesn't work either.

My React App file

```
import data from './Data'

class App extends Component {
  render()  {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Home data={data} />
        <About />
        <Portfolio data={data} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Data file:

```
let Data = {
  portfolio: [
    {
      name: "picture1",
      discription: "First Model",
      status: "sold",
      img: '/images/picture1.jpg',
      alt: "pr1",
    },
  ],
};
```

The picture is located at "project/images/picture1.jpg"

My actual Portfolio Component which should display this picture:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Portfolio.css';

export default class Portfolio extends Component {
  render() {
    let data = this.props.data;
    return (
      <section id="home">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="card">
            {data.portfolio &&
              data.portfolio.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <img src={item.img} alt={item.alt}/>
                      <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                      <p>{item.discription}</p>
                      <p>{item.status}</p>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to import dynamically using require:

```
<img src={require(item.img)} alt={item.alt}/>
```

Comment: I tried it. My complete content is disappearing and i get a warning    Compiled with warnings.

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./src/components/Portfolio.js 20:23-40
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

webpack compiled with 1 warning

Comment: @Jonny how you initialised your React project? If you are under Create React App, add at the end `.default` `<img src={require(item.img).default} alt={item.alt}/>`

Comment: I created it with "npm create-react-app" only the react router is installed yet. still the same output. I dont know if it is a problem of my css at the end. i gave the picture for firstly a width and height of 250px. But still the same. All other content disappear when i use "<img src={require(item.img).default} alt={item.alt}/>"

Comment: Can you share in a codepen or somewhere? it will be easier. 
Can you try to import using template literals: require(`${item.img}`).default

`<img src={require(`${item.img}`).default} alt={item.alt}/>`

Comment: Is seems like that i came on a solution. I imported first the image import image1 from '../src/images/picture1.png. Then i passed it into my data array where i use the image "image" : picture1, This works for me.